# How to assign values to dynamic names variables

Tags: r

Hi I'm trying to name variables using a for loop so I get dynamic names for my variables.

```
for (i in 1:nX) {
    paste("X",i, sep="")=datos[,i+1]
    next
}
```

Comment: Why are you trying to do that? Use the array instead.

Comment: Hi, I have a data frame with long headers but would like to automatically set my own variables as X1, X2, etc so I can operate with them individually

Comment: Why don't you just do `colNames(datos) <- paste("X", i, sep="")` then? Then you can access them with `datos$X1`, `datos$X2` etc

Comment: Thanks nico that is a nice solution!

Comment: This is faq 7.21, the most important part of that answer is the last part that says not to do this, use a list or environment.

Comment: is there a canonical version of this "dynamically name variables" question that I can start using as a duplicate target? (The answers here are OK, but I'd prefer a question where at least one of the answers spells out the classic "use a list instead"/FAQ 7.21 logic ...)

Answer (score 34, accepted):

use `assign` as in:

```
x <- 1:10

for(i in seq_along(x)){
  assign(paste('X', i, sep=''), x[i])
}
```

Comment: Hi David, why do you think is a bad idea?

Comment: @user1228124 Experienced R programmers generally advise against using `assign` unless you are absolutely forced to. In this case, nico's suggestion of using `colnames<-` is safer, simpler, and easier to understand.

Comment: plus one, this saved me time

Answer (score 12):

It can be a good idea to use `assign` when there are many variables and they are looked up frequently. Lookup in an environment is faster than in vector or list. A separate environment for the data objects is a good idea.

Another idea is to use the `hash` package. It performs lookup as fast as environments, but is more comfortable to use.

```
datos <- rnorm(1:10)
library(hash)
h <- hash(paste("x", 1:10, sep=""), datos)
h[["x1"]]
```

Here is a timing comparision for 10000 vars that are looked up 10^5 times:

```
datos <- rnorm(1:10000)
lookup <- paste("x", sample.int(length(datos), 100000, replace=TRUE), sep="")

# method 1, takes 16s on my machine
names(datos) <- paste("x", seq_along(datos), sep="")
system.time(for(key in lookup) datos[[key]])

# method 2, takes 1.6s on my machine
library(hash)
h <- hash(paste("x", seq_along(datos), sep=""), datos)
system.time(for(key in lookup) h[[key]])

# method 3, takes 0.2s on my machine
e <- new.env()
for(i in seq_along(datos)){
  assign(paste('x', i, sep=''), datos[i], envir=e)
}
system.time(for(key in lookup) e[[key]])
```

However, the vectorized version of method 1 is the fastest, but is not always applicable

```
# method 4, takes 0.02s
names(datos) <- paste("x", seq_along(datos), sep="")
system.time(datos[lookup])
```