# Dynamically call dataframe column & conditional replacement in R

Tags: r

First question post. Please excuse any formatting issues that may be present.

What I'm trying to do is conditionally replace a factor level in a dataframe column. Reason being due to unicode differences between a right single quotation mark (U+2019) and an apostrophe (U+0027).

All of the columns that need this replacement begin with with "INN8", so I'm using

```
grep("INN8", colnames(demoDf)) -> apostropheFixIndices
for(i in apostropheFixIndices) {
    levels(demoDfFinal[i]) <- c(levels(demoDf[i]), "I definitely wouldn't")
    (insert code here)
}
```

to get the indices in order to perform the conditional replacement.

I've taken a look at a myriad of questions that involve naming variables on the fly: [naming variables on the fly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2679193/how-to-name-variables-on-the-fly-in-r)

as well as [how to assign values to dynamic variables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14081982/how-to-assign-values-to-dynamic-names-variables-in-r)

and have explored the R-FAQ [on turning a string into a variable](https://cran.r-project.org/doc/FAQ/R-FAQ.html#How-can-I-turn-a-string-into-a-variable_003f) and looked into Ari Friedman's suggestion that named elements in a list are preferred. However I'm unsure as to the execution as well as the significance of the best practice suggestion.

I know I need to do something along the lines of

```
demoDf$INN8xx[demoDf$INN8xx=="I definitely wouldn’t"] <- "I definitely wouldn't"]
```

but the iterations I've tried so far haven't worked.

Thank you for your time!

Comment: And just using `gsub` won't work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, then you don't want to rename the columns. Then this might work:

```
demoDf <- data.frame(A=rep("I definitely wouldn’t",10) , B=rep("I definitely wouldn’t",10))
newDf  <- apply(demoDf, 2, function(col) { 
  gsub(pattern="’", replacement = "'", x = col) 
})
```

It just checks all columns for the wrong symbol.

Or if you have a vector containing the column indices you want to check then you could go with

```
# Let's say you identified columns 2, 5 and 8
cols <- c(2,5,8)
sapply(cols, function(col) { 
  demoDf[,col] <<- gsub(pattern="’", replacement = "'", x = demoDf[,col])
})
```

Comment: how do i preserve the factor levels and label info?

Comment: How does the data exactly look like? Maybe just wrap a call to `factors` around the `gsub` ?

Comment: I am not at home right now so I can't check for myself. If it does not work I'll look into it later on ;)